# word choice: "reserve to"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm wondering if "reserved" is a correct word choice in the following:

“Pterosaurs preserved in such quality are exceedingly rare and are usually **reserved** to select rock formations in Brazil and China. And yet, an enormous superbly preserved pterosaur emerged from a tidal platform in Scotland,” said Natalia Jagielska, a doctoral student at the University of Edinburgh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to me. I suspect that the author meant "restricted" but got confused after writing "preserved" and simply wrote something that sounded similar.

Answer (score 0):

"Reserved" can mean "limited to". Like, "This area is reserved for hunting and fishing."

Note this meaning is related to the meaning "scheduled for" or "set aside for". Like, "I would like to reserve a room at your hotel for next Thursday and Friday." You're asking them to set aside a room for you, to limit one to you and no one else.

So yes, it makes sense in this context. This type of fossil usually only occurs in this type of rock formation. It is "reserved" to this type of rock formation.

People don't use the word "reserve" with this meaning very much any more so the use here may well be confusing. If I was writing it I probably would have written "usually limited to" or some such.